# React Admin with ra-data-hasura Error: Unknown resource . Make sure it has been declared on your server side schema

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-admin, hasura

I'm using `React Admin` with `GraphQL` and `ra-data-hasura`.

My problem is that the Introspection Query is made only when the app starts (when the user has the role of a guest before logging in). After login, the Introspection Query does not retrieve updated data, leading to errors for resources the logged-in user should access. After a reload, a new introspection query is executed and the resources are available.

Any ideas on how can I force the introspection query after login or refresh the entire data provider?

[image]

I tried to force re-fetching the Introspection Query, but it did not work. I think it needs a full data provider refresh to work.

Comment: Could you share your code? In this case, you will receive a better answer.